# Is the named let tail recursive?

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion, let

These two examples do the factorial of a number:

```
(define (factorial n)
  (define (execute n result)
    (cond
         [(> 2 n) result]
         [else (execute (- n 1) (* result n))]))
  (execute n 1))
```

And

```
(define (factorial n)
  (let loop ((curr n)
             (result 1))
    (cond
         [(> 2 curr) result]
         [else (loop (- curr 1) (* result curr))])))
```

The difference reside in using the named-let. Are they both pure and tail recursive functions?

Comment: This case yes, but named `let` can be used in non tail recursion as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are tail-recursive, and they're essentially equivalent.

A named let is just a shorthand for a function definition along with a first call using the initial values as the arguments.

A function is tail-recursive if all its calls to itself are in tail positions, i.e. it simply returns the value of that call. In the first function, the recursive call to `execute` is in the tail position; in the second function the same is true of the call to `loop`.